# Invite people who liked my first page to like another one in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-like

I'm the admin of a certain Facebook page, "A". Some people I don't know personally and I'm not friend with liked this page.

Now I created a 2nd page, "B". Since the topics are similar, I'd like to invite all the people from page "A" to also like page "B".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't invite someone from one page to another.

You can only invite your friends to a page so you can invite someone from your friends list but not from another page like list.

Comment: This might very well be true, but it would be even better if you could link to any kind of documentation to back it up.

Comment: I accepted this because I came to the same conclusion. Still, a reference would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, all you have to do is send it out to them by tagging them and letting them know.